# Integrating ajax, jquery based webservices with android

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, json, parsing

I am trying to consume a webservice currently made in ajax. I have no idea what this web service is actually doing other than it uses POST Data. When i try to see its output on POSTMAN (Rest api client) I am getting errors.

This is the structure of web service :

```
var request = {};
request.UserName = "some data"; // this should be always hard coded like this 
request.Password = "some data";  // this should be always hard coded like this
request.CurrentUsername = "admin"; //   this is hard coded like this for now 

request.FirstName = "some data";
request.LastName = "some data";

var send = {};
send.request = request;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "some link",
    data: JSON.stringify(send),
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    success: function (msg) {
        // Process the result here
    },
    error: function () {
        //alert("error");
        // Display the error here in the front end
    }
});
});
});
```

I need to get its output in android. Since i have little knowledge in ajax, jquery(backend) and done json parsing(in android) with post method using web service link and parameters. Please guide me how to implement in this case.

Moreover i usually check web service output on postman but here it is giving me bad request every time.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes finally got a way to move it. It is very simple and following header is needed in android end thats all

```
httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using [Fiddler4](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) by Telerik? i was struggling for 2 weeks at work doing something very similiar to this. I was using webclient to send data from Android to my web page. I got errors non stop. nothing online helped. using fiddler i was able to see what my post data was and where it was and all details. it should help you narrow down a lot of things.